# How to update value in-place

Tags: ruby

Is there a way to update values in-place using `each`? For example,

```
[1,2,3].each{|i| i = i * i }
```

does not produce `[1, 4, 9]`. I could use `map!` or `collect!`, but I was wondering if there is a way to do something similar with `each`.

Comment: Isn't `map!` or `collect!` just the answer? What exactly do you mean by *similar to `each`*?

Comment: piggybacking on what YuHao said, `map!` seems like the right thing to use.  maybe you could provide a use case for what you are trying to do?

Comment: If those were my requirements then yes that would be the answer, but I am doing an exercism exercise and it says specifically "Keep your hands off that collect/map/fmap ..." so no that isn't the answer. I am trying to see if there are other ways to iterate over an array and updated it in-place.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a very strange request, but yes:

If the array is in a variable it is easy:

```
numbers = [1, 2, 3]
numbers.each.with_index { |number, index| numbers[index] = number * number }
```

If it is not, things are tricky. I have no idea why you will want to modify it in place if you don't have a reference to it, but here we go:

```
[1, 2, 3].instance_eval { each.with_index { |number, index| self[index] = number * number } }
```

Comment: Thanks the second option was what I was looking for. Really interesting use of instance_eval.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this with objects but not with values.

```
a = [{x: 1}, {x: 2}]
a.each { |obj| obj[:x] = 3 }
a # [{:x=>3}, {:x=>3}]
```

With values, the assignment occurs causing the local variable `i` to take a different value, but this doesn't change the original integer inside the array.

Comment: I think he was just asking how to achieve `map!` with `each`, not change what a specific integer points to. He wouldn't have even mentioned an array if that was the case.

Answer (score 1):

You can manipulate the array within the each block...

```
array = [1, 2, 3]
array.each {i = array.shift; array << i * i }
p array
=> [1, 4, 9]
```

Comment: Yeah, @ndn, but I got loads of it. :)