# Delete leading nils from Array

Tags: ruby

I have an Array like so:

```
[nil, nil, nil, 2, 4, 6, 1, nil, nil, 3, 4, 6]
```

What I need is a nice way to remove all *leading* nils in place (so `compact!` is bad), and get number of nils removed (so `drop_while` is bad).

Comment: Why do you want to remove leading `nil`s but not every other one?  What's the rationale for this?  What problem are you attempting to solve?  The reason I ask:  keeping `nil` in an otherwise homogeneous array doesn't make a lot of sense.

Comment: This is simply a queue that allows `nil`, but when it has multiple nils in a row there is a nice optimization that I can squeeze in if I have length of such nil-row. I can of course solve this with `drop_while` and `size` subtraction, but it really ruins readability of other-ways very pretty code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably not a good idea, but if you insist on a one-liner:

```
arr.instance_eval { shift(index { |element| !element.nil? } || size) }.count
```

---

**EDIT**: For anyone's future reference, the better looking version that we agreed upon:

```
arr.shift(arr.index(&:itself) || arr.size).count
```

Comment: Very inventive, similar to the revision of my answer, which I posted seconds after you did.

Comment: @CarySwoveland, thanks! Still don't think it's a good idea to use in practice dough. :)

Comment: A good answer is one that helps others learn something new about Ruby. That may be how to implement best practices or how to use a method they are not familiar with, which here could be [BasicObject#instance_eval](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/BasicObject.html#method-i-instance_eval).

Comment: @ndn this is nice, when you spell it `arr.shift(arr.index &:itself).count` instead of with `instance_eval` it's not looking that bad at all

Comment: @Borsunho, the reason I did it with instance eval is that I didn't know if you were going to use it with an array stored in a variable or written in place. One would wonder why would anyone want to `shift` an array to which he does not have a reference to, but I got this question in the past xd

Comment: [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31240414/how-to-update-value-in-place/31240585#31240585) is that strange question! xd

Comment: @ndn that was indeed very strange request

Comment: Notice there is a problem with both approaches (and with my initial solution as well) if `arr = [nil, nil, nil]`.

Comment: @CarySwoveland, true that.

Comment: Luckily for me, that is guaranteed not to happen.

Comment: Even though the OP doesn't have to be concerned if `arr` contains only `nil`s, you could deal with that case, making the method more robust, by writing: `arr.shift(arr.index(&:itself) || arr.size).count`.

Comment: @CarySwoveland, It was late here and I decided to go to sleep. Just thought of the same thing this morning on the way to work. Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

Here are three ways of doing that. Note the following has gone through several edits.

```
arr0 = [nil, nil, nil, 2, 4, 6, 1, nil, nil, 3, 4, 6]
arr1 = [nil, nil]
arr2 = [1, 2]
```

**#1**

```
def remove_leading_nils(arr)
  i = arr.index { |e| !e.nil? } || arr.size
  arr.slice!(0...i)
  i
end

remove_leading_nils(arr0) #=> 3
arr0                      #=> [2, 4, 6, 1, nil, nil, 3, 4, 6] 

remove_leading_nils(arr1) #=> 2
arr1                      #=> [] 

remove_leading_nils(arr2) #=> 0
arr2                      #=> [1,2]
```

**#2**

```
def remove_leading_nils(arr)
  arr.size.times.with_object([]) { |_,a| a << arr.shift unless arr.first }.size
end
```

**#3**

I prefer this one because it's simpler and I think it reads best:

```
def remove_leading_nils(arr)
  sz = arr.size
  arr.shift while !arr.empty? && arr.first.nil?
  sz - arr.size
end
```

Methods #2 and #3 have the same return values for `arr0`, `arr1` and `arr2` as does method #1.